# How do I get Elasticsearch to add .keyword field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get fields with the name "IP" to be mapped as "ip" type with a .keyword field of type "keyword". The following mapping is not creating the .keyword field. How do I make elastic map this field?

```
"IP": {
    "type": "ip",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you witness that the keyword sub-field is not being created?

Comment: The fields were not showing up in Kibana Visualizations. Turns out I needed to flush the index after mappings are created.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing an example for you to test it.

**Please note that after you add the `keyword` field you should run POST index_name/_update_by_query to update the existing data.**

###### create the index

```
PUT test_ip
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "IP": {
        "type": "ip"
      },
      "other_fields": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

###### (working) update the mapping with _mapping API

```
PUT test_ip/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "IP": {
      "type": "ip",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

###### (error) If you are testing like the following, you will get an error.

```
PUT test_ip
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "IP": {
        "type": "ip",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

###### The error:

```
> {   "error": {
>     "root_cause": [
>       {
>         "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
>         "reason": "index [test_ip/xBXNCAjnRjODoAAY3TGFBA] already exists",
>         "index_uuid": "xBXNCAjnRjODoAAY3TGFBA",
>         "index": "test_ip"
>       }
>     ],
>     "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
>     "reason": "index [test_ip/xBXNCAjnRjODoAAY3TGFBA] already exists",
>     "index_uuid": "xBXNCAjnRjODoAAY3TGFBA",
>     "index": "test_ip"   },
>.    "status": 400 }
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Need to flush the index after mappings are created.

The mappings are being created dynamically with dynamic mapping rules. When the first object comes through the new mapping is created. This information does not make it to Visualizations in Kibana immediately. You may have to flush the index after the mapping is created to make the new fields populate when building Visualizations.

Comment: What do you mean by "flushing" the index?

Comment: I logged into Kibana under Stack Management. One of the actions was "Flush Index" and "Refresh Index". After running both of those, the new values were present in the Kibana UI. My guess is that Kibana does not always immediately reflect changes in Elasticsearch. This forces Kibana to update.

Comment: What version of ES/Kibana are you using?